# AUCTeX: changing BiBTeX templates

Tags: auctex

when creating bibliographies (i.e., bib-files) with AUCTeX, one can use pre-formatted templates (e.g, for @Book, @InCollection etc.). When printing such a template a problem I have is, that it comes with many fields that I use very seldom. Usually, I just need five fields or so, yet AUCTeX will provide me with roughly 20 fields (among them OPTnote, OPTannote etc.), most of them unnecessary.

Hence my question, is it possible to change these templates somewhere?